# What's the name of the control that has buttons for auto-hidden windows like the one used in Visual Studio 2005/2008? (.Net)

Tags: .net, winforms

In Visual Studio when you click the Auto-hide thumbtack looking icon the window will collapse into a band that has buttons for each hidden window for the docking area.

I've seen this in other apps so I assume its a control that I haven't found or figured out how to use yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework does not include a control that has that behavior out-of-the-box (I believe it's called a dockable pane control). However, numerous third parties offer controls that mimic it quite well:

http://www.codejock.com/products/dockingpane/

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/windockmanager.aspx